# mkp.yieldUnescaped not working

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I am really stuck here.  I am creating an XML document with Groovy 1.7 and everything is working except one section is being escaped when it shouldn't.

I am starting out like this:

```
            triadDoc = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlTriadMessageDocumentPath)
            writer = new StringWriter()
            xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
            writer = xmlBuilder.bind {mkp.yield triadDoc}
```

which works great.  Then I'm adding to the document like this:

```
            triadDoc.TriadPayload.Payload[0] = "<![CDATA[" + xmlBuilder.bind {mkp.yieldUnescaped dto.getCcdDoc()} + "]]>"
```

This does not work as I want - I end up with this:

```
            & lt;![CDATA[& lt;ClinicalDocument& gt;... (added extra blank to the escape sequences)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've looked all over the Internet for a clue.  Thanks!!

Comment: I refuse to help someone writing software for the Triads

Comment: ?? Triad is an internal message format/schema at my company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the whole CDATA block to yieldUnescaped

```
 mkp.yieldUnescaped( "<![CDATA[.....
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The CDATA section in a document is ignored by a parser.

maybe that is what is causing this thing to skip.

the four characters need to be together inorder to get you the '<' and '>' values.

<![CDATA[<ClinicalDocument>...

Comment: yes, as i stated above, i inserted the blank to allow me to show that it is not working properly.  If i remove the blank, it looks like it is working (for rendering on this site)